# SSIS package execution through VB.net code

Tags: ssis, package

I've kept my ssis package in my local application folder and through vb.net m able to execute that as package.execute(), But when i publish the same code in my server, its showing some eror,

so is that we need to install sql server in the applicaiton server also ?

My server does'nt have sql server installed....

or any prerequisite do we need to install on my server machine to make this work....

Comment: Can you post more details on the error that you're getting? Is there any way of debugging the code on the server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need to install sql server integration services on that server

Comment: But watever the assembly needed for executing the package i've kept that assembly in my application folder n i am accesing from there, its enough right????

Comment: Hi, I've installed only Sql server Integration services component in my server, still its showing error